# How to create custom shape using CSS3 to match this?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a graph details, but i would like to show using css shapes. for that i am trying to create a `css3` shapes to match my graphics ( see attached ) but i am not able to get the result.

How to reproduce this graphics?

[image: Here is the image]

my try: this is very bad:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="triangle-red"></div>
    <div id="triangle-blue"></div>
    <div id="triangle-yellow"></div>
</div>

#triangle-red {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 100px solid red;
}

#triangle-blue {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-top: 100px solid blue;
}
#triangle-yellow 
{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 100px solid yellow;
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
}
```

[demo online](http://jsfiddle.net/swd7bay4/)

Note: according to the values of each comb, i would like the calculate the height and width, by the data what i am getting. (it's like graph)

Comment: I'm not sure those shapes can be created using "css shapes" (looks like you're using borders), not without some sort of CSS transforms anyway.

Comment: Can you post your ideas please?

Comment: A `<canvas>` may be a better approach. Two libraries I would recommend is [D3](http://www.visualcinnamon.com/2013/09/making-d3-radar-chart-look-bit-better.html) and [Flot](http://jumflot.jumware.com/examples/Experimental/Spider.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you will need 6 divs.

every div is triangle : to make one with css check [this](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/)

use [transform:rotate(xdeg](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp))

for the shadows just change the color.

also use [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) to make the red divs above the *blues*

Comment: As like your Idea, I tried here. still can you help me to fine tune or show me even good approach. http://jsfiddle.net/u78bQ/441/